# AJAX HtmlEditorExtender and getting text from the textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, htmleditorextender

I'm just starting to get to grips with web development and trying to build up some experience.
I am implementing the HtmlEditorExtender in my website.  I have added all the files and references necessary to use this control and I've got the control displaying correctly.  The problem I'm having is I don't seem to be able to get the content of the textbox after making changes. 
I have attached the control to a textbox, then populated the textbox with the content I wish to edit.  Once I've made changes I have a save button that will save the current content in the HTML editor.  What I'm seeing is that the Text property of the Textbox is exactly the same as before I made the changes.  Is there something obvious that I'm missing.

Code is below:

Markup in UserControl:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="background-color: #DDDDDD; border: solid 1px Gray;
     color: Black;">
        <p>
            Edit:
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHTMLContent" CssClass="WhiteTextBox" TextMode="MultiLine"
            Columns="50" Rows="10" />
        <br />
        <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="htmlEditor" TargetControlID="txtHTMLContent" Runat="server" EnableSanitization="false" />
    <center>    
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </center>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string content = GetContent();
    txtHTMLContent.Text = content;
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseManager dm = new DatabaseManager();
    dm.UpdateContent(txtHTMLContent.Text);
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap txtHTMLContent initialization code in the Page_Load method in `if(!IsPostback)` check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string content = GetContent();
        txtHTMLContent.Text = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, should have thought of that.  Got it working now :)